Web scraping using R: read_html_live() - correct css selector to perform click
Here is my base url: https://obchody.heureka.sk/?f=1
This contains a list of online shops and I want to scrape their base urs. However urls are not present on this page, because this is treated by java script. I need to perform a click on each online shop logo or name, which redirects me to the home page of the shop and I can get the url from there.
I am having troubles perform the click; I did not succeed with Rvest read_html_live() nor with Selenider elem_click().
My code for Rvest read_html_live():
url <- "https://obchody.heureka.sk/?f=1"
page <- read_html_live(url)
page$click(".c-shops-table__cell--name a", n_clicks = 1)

Code for Selenider
selenider_session()
selenider::open_url(url)
s(".c-shops-table__cell--name a") %>% elem_click(js = TRUE, timeout = NULL)

My expectation is that I should get redirected to the online shop home page; but none of the above works.
What am I doing wrong please?

If you are using Chrome, there is an extension called SelectorGadget. When you install and activate the extension, simply click on the html element of interest on the webpage and it will fetch the right CSS code for you which you can now use in your R script.

I have that extension but usually I do not use it; I prefer to specify selectors myself. In this particular case it does not work for me; I am getting either "No valid path found" or just entire screen green... But thanks for advice anyway...

URLs in this example are not mapped / translated with JavaScript, it's server-side HTTP redirection. So you can collect URLs with rvest, iterate through a list of URLs (with map(), for example), use httr/httr2 to make a request while disabling redirection and collect the actual target location from response header:
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
library(purrr)

# collect redirect location from response header
get_redirect <- function(url_, rate = 1){
  request(url_) |>
    req_options(followlocation = FALSE) |>
    req_throttle(1) |>
    req_perform() |> 
    resp_header("Location")
}

urls <- 
  read_html("https://obchody.heureka.sk/?f=1") |>
  html_elements(".c-shops-table__cell--name a") |>
  html_attr("href")

head(urls)
#> [1] "https://www.heureka.sk/exit/alza-sk/?z=4"      
#> [2] "https://www.heureka.sk/exit/mall-sk/?z=4"      
#> [3] "https://www.heureka.sk/exit/datart-sk/?z=4"    
#> [4] "https://www.heureka.sk/exit/kaufland-sk/?z=4"  
#> [5] "https://www.heureka.sk/exit/andreashop-sk/?z=4"
#> [6] "https://www.heureka.sk/exit/mironetcz-sk/?z=4"

# get redirects for 1st 5 urls
urls[1:5] |>
  set_names() |>
  map_chr(get_redirect, .progress = TRUE) |>
  tibble::enframe(name = "url", value = "redirect")

#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   url                                            redirect                       
#>   <chr>                                          <chr>                          
#> 1 https://www.heureka.sk/exit/alza-sk/?z=4       http://www.alza.sk?hgtid=7d6b6…
#> 2 https://www.heureka.sk/exit/mall-sk/?z=4       http://www.mall.sk?hgtid=da6c5…
#> 3 https://www.heureka.sk/exit/datart-sk/?z=4     https://www.datart.sk/?hgtid=f…
#> 4 https://www.heureka.sk/exit/kaufland-sk/?z=4   https://www.kaufland.sk?hgtid=…
#> 5 https://www.heureka.sk/exit/andreashop-sk/?z=4 http://www.andreashop.sk?hgtid…

Created on 2024-05-22 with reprex v2.1.0
I'd guess your page$click()fails because your 1st request hits a cookie wall (do check page$view() ) and/or page$click() does not really work if selector returns multiple matches.

this is super useful, I learned a lot from your post, thank you!
I was not able to make working page$click. I think that I was not able to find the correct CSS selector. I tried different equivalents of code below, but with no luck:
 page$click(".c-shops-table__cell--name a:first-of-type", n_clicks = 1)
May I have a side-question please? Do you know how to make working read_html_live() with proxy?
Many thanks once again.
